# Is there a Hadoop/Hive setting that influences how column headers are returned?

Tags: hadoop, hive

semi-SQL literate QA guy here!

We're adding Hadoop/Hive integration into our product for a client.  I've been given a build to test, and I'm running into a problem - the SQL statements I'm using are returning Hive table column headers in lowercase.

For example:

If my SQL is:  "select FIRST_NAME from recipient_data;"

My query is returning:  "first_name"

My product is case-sensitive, and the engineer helping me troubleshoot this issue says it seems to be a function of our Hadoop driver, and not anything our program is doing with the returned values.  Is there a way to configure Hadoop/Hive to not lowercase the column headers it returns?

Comment: It makes more sense to check the driver definitions. Which driver are you using?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - we're running Hive 1.1.0.

Comment: And the (jdbc?) driver?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - Sorry, the Hive driver is 0.13.1, and the JDBC driver I'm using is whatever comes with SQLWorkbenchJ.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz > I stand corrected.